# How can I use an if condition in model.py Django?

Tags: django-models

I would like if a student studies "Computer Science", for example, that in the "Categories" class he can only select certain "Categories". Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
ERRORS:
accounds.Categories.members: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'accounds.Categories.members' clashes with reverse query name for 'accounds.Categories.members_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accounds.Categories.members' or 'accounds.Categories.members_ptr'.
```

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

# Create your models here.
class Members(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(default=date.today, null=True)
    vorname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    nachname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    Studiengang = (("IT & Technik","IT & Technik") ,("Designs & Medie", "Designs & Medie"),
                   ("Personal & Recht","Personal & Recht"), ("Informatik","Informatik"))
    studiengang = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=Studiengang)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    passwort = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vorname

class Categories(Members):

    if Members.studiengang == "Informatik":
        Kategorien = (
            ("Mathematik Grundlagen I", "Mathematik Grundlagen I"),
            ("Grundlagen der industriellen Softwaretechnik", "Grundlagen der industriellen  
Softwaretechnik"),

        )
        kategorien = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=Kategorien)





    members = models.ForeignKey(Members, null=True,on_delete= models.SET_NULL)




class Statistik(models.Model):
    fragen_insgesammt = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    fragen_richtig_beantwortet = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    fragen_falsch_beantwortet = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    anzahl_der_punkte = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    student =  models.ForeignKey(Members, null=True,on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
```

I would be super happy if someone could help

Answer (score 0):

### in Categories Model > members ForeignKey add argument (related_name)

```
members = models.ForeignKey(Members, null=True,on_delete= models.SET_NULL,related_name="members_list")
```